# Reading TCS34725 with MSP430G2553

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, embedded, msp430, texas-instruments

I'm trying to read the red color data from the TCS34725 color sensor that is attached to this board by Grove (https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-I2C-Color-Sensor-V2.html) by combining its low value and high value bits to give me one final value to then turn on an LED that is connected to my MSP430G2553 to indicate that a dominant color is detected.

In debugging this however, my other electronics cease to function and I have a suspicion that it may be that the main loop is getting stuck on the portion of code for my color sensor. Currently, I have a Gikfun capacitive moisture sensor and a temperature sensor (TMP 117) that are able to run properly and indicate a threshold was passed with their respective lEDs. Then, when integrating my color sensor I wind up in some issues. Here is my code so far

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


unsigned int RxByteCtr;
unsigned int RxWord;





/**
 * main.c
 */
int main(void)
{

    // I2C Set up

    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;                    // stop watchdog timer
    P1DIR |= BIT0;
    P1SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                        // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0
    P1SEL2|= BIT6 + BIT7;                        // Assign I2C Pins to USCI_B0
    // P2DIR |= BIT0;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                         // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;        // I2C Master, synchronous mode
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;               // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
    UCB0BR0 = 12;                                // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100KHz
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                        // Clear SW reset, Resume Operation
    IE2 |= UCB0RXIE;                             // Enable RX Interrupt
    TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2;                     // SMCLK, Continuous Mode

    // ADC Set up
    ADC10CTL0 = ADC10SHT_2 + ADC10ON + ADC10IE;  // adc on interrupt enabled
    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_1;                          // INPUT A1
    ADC10AE0 |= 0x02;                            // PA.1 ADC OPTION SELECT
    P1DIR |= BIT3;                               // 1.3 OUTPUT



    while(1)
    {
        // Analog Sensing (Moisture)
        ADC10CTL0  = ADC10SHT_2 + ADC10ON + ADC10IE; // ADC on, interrupt enabled
        ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;              // SAMPLING AND CONVERSION START
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);         // LPM0 ADC10ISR WILL FORCE EXIT
        if(ADC10MEM < 0x1FF)
            P1OUT |= BIT3;                       // LED OFF (DRY)
        else
            P1OUT &= ~BIT3;                      // LED ON (WET)

        // TMP117 Sensing (Temperature)
        UCB0I2CSA = 0x48;                        // Set Slave Address (TMP117)
        RxByteCtr = 2;                           // Receiver Byte Counter Loaded
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                     // Start Condition for I2C
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);         // Enter Low power mode, enable interrupts
                                                 // Remain until all data is received

        if(RxWord < 0xE05)                       // Greater than 28C?
            P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                      // No, P1.0 = 0 (LED OFF)
        else
            P1OUT |= BIT0;                       // Yes, P1.0 = 1 (LED ON)

      /*  __disable_interrupt();
        TACCTL0 |= CCIE;                         // TACCR0 Interrupt enabled
        __bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);         // Enter Low power mode enable interrupts remain until TACCR0 interrupt occurs
        TACCTL0 &= ~CCIE;                        // TACCR0 interrupt disabled
     */


        UCB0I2CSA = 0x29;
        IE2 |= UCB0TXIE;
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;

        UCB0TXBUF = 0x80 | 0x00;
        UCB0TXBUF = 0x01 | 0x02;

        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;

        uint8_t redLow, redHigh;
        uint16_t redColor;

        UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
        redLow = UCB0RXBUF;

        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;
        UCB0TXBUF = 0x80 | 0x17;

        UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
        redHigh = UCB0RXBUF;

        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;

        redColor = (redHigh << 8) | redLow;

        if(redColor >= 1)
            P2OUT |= BIT0;
        else
            P2OUT &= ~BIT0;



// INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINES DEFINITIONS
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC_)
#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void TA0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(TIMER0_A0_VECTOR))) TA0_ISR(void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);          // Exit Low power mode
}

// ADC10 ISR
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=ADC10_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC10_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC10_VECTOR))) ADC10_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);
}

// USCIAB0TX_ISR receives 2+ number of bytes by preloading RxByteCtr with byte count.
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCIAB0TX_VECTOR))) USCIAB0TX_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
    RxByteCtr--;                                // Decrement counter

    if(RxByteCtr)
    {
        RxWord = (unsigned int)UCB0RXBUF << 8;  // Get Byte
        if (RxByteCtr == 1)                     // If only one byte left
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                // Generate Stop condition
    }
    else
    {
        RxWord |= UCB0RXBUF;                    // Get final byte and combine MSB and LSB
        __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit Lower power mode
    }
}
```

What I know so far about initializing the TCS color sensor is that I have to set the slave address, write a command to the Enable Register to power the device (PON), and then also - in that same register - write to the RGBC enable field (AEN) to activate its two channel ADC and that a minimum interval of 2.4 ms must pass after PON is asserted before the RGBC can be initiated. Here is a link to its data sheet (https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove-I2C_Color_Sensor/res/TCS3472%20Datasheet.pdf) and one to the MSP430G2553 (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf)

I had tried to issue `while(!(IFG & UCB0TXIFG));` and `while(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);` in an earlier iteration just after the start commands, yet, in debugging when I click pause those lines would get highlighted every time leading me to believe it's stuck in that waiting phase. I'm not sure what else I could try here any help in initializing the device and reading from the appropriate registers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Create a new project that only accesses this sensor. Use TI's example code for I2C.